Pentagon $(ABCDE)$ is inscribed in a circle of radius $1$. If $\angle DEA=\angle EAB = \angle ABC$ and $m\angle CAD=60^{\circ}$ and $BC=2AB$.
Pentagon $(ABCDE)$ is inscribed in a circle of radius $1$. If $\angle DEA=\angle EAB = \angle ABC$ and $m\angle CAD=60^{\circ}$ and $BC=2AB$.
Compute the area of $(ABCDE)$

Firstly I noticed that triangle $ADC$ must be isosceles. Thus making the angle $\angle ADC = \angle ACD = 60^{\circ}$. Then by the cyclic quadrilateral $ACDE$, we obtain:
$\angle DEA = 120^{\circ}$.
The area of $(ABCDE)=(ACD)+2(ADE)$ which then turns into $(ABCDE)=\sqrt{3}(\frac{AD^{2}}{4}+\frac{AB^{2}}{2})$
I'm not sure where I can obtain $AD$ or $AB$ from here...

Let's define:
$$
\angle BOA=\angle EOD=\alpha,
\quad\text{and consequently:}\quad
\angle COB=\angle AOE=120°-\alpha.
$$
From $BC=2AB$ we obtain the equation:
$$
\sin{120°-\alpha\over2}=2\sin{\alpha\over2}
$$
which can be solved to:
$$
\tan{\alpha\over2}={\sqrt3\over5}\implies
\cos{\alpha\over2}={5\over2\sqrt7},\ 
\sin{\alpha\over2}={\sqrt3\over2\sqrt7},\ 
\sin\alpha={5\sqrt3\over14},\ 
\cos\alpha={11\over14}.
$$
The area of the pentagon is the sum of the areas of triangles
$BOA$, $EOD$, $COB$, $AOE$ and $DOC$:
$$
\text{area}=\sin\alpha+\sin(120°-\alpha)+{1\over2}\sin120°=
{5\sqrt3\over14}+{4\sqrt3\over7}+{\sqrt3\over4}=
{33\sqrt3\over28}.
$$


Could you shed some light on how $BC=2AB$ implies that $\sin{120°-\alpha\over2}=2\sin{\alpha\over2}$?

Ah nevermind, I saw that If I apply the sine rule on triangle $ABC$ and the fact that the angle $\angle CAB=60^{\circ}-\frac{\alpha}{2}$, I could get the result.
Anyways, your solution looks great, thanks!

Then why don't you mark it as accepted?
